# Setting a custom dimension in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have created a custom dimension with hit option and have created the data variable for the same and added the variable in the **universal page view tag**.

I am passing the variable as below, I am able to see the data layer variable in the **GTM debug mode**, but secondary dimension filter for custom dimension is not showing up any result.

```
var WebServiceId = "@Request.Cookies["WebServiceId"].Value";
var affiliationId = "@queryStringCollection["A"].ToString()";
dataLayer.push({ 'WebServiceId': WebServiceId });
dataLayer.push({ 'AffiliationCode': affiliationId });
ga('set', 'WebServiceId', WebServiceId);
ga('set', 'AffiliationCode', affiliationId);
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GTM you cannot (or at least should not) use ga.set calls. Instead you do the configuration inside the Google Analytics tag.

Also, adding the dimension to the dataLayer is not enough to have it send to GA.

You need to

- Create the custom dimension in GA
- Remember the numeric index for your newly created dimension
- in GTM create new variables of the dataLayer type  with your keys that you pushed to the dataLayer
- in GTM in your Ga tag look for the custom dimension tab
- add the numeric index of your dimension in the "index" input field, and the variable in the value field
- save and publish
- wait a while (since it might take up to a day before the values show up)

Comment: Hi Eike, Thanks for your comments. I have already added the index and data layer variable in the Univeral analytics tag. But then also I am not able to see the value in reports. I have done this steps 2 days ago.